# composition of piecewise functions with even/odd conditions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, piecewise-continuity

I have the functions: $f,g \in \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}):$

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2}, & \text{if }n \text{ is even}\\
n+1, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$

$g(n) =
\begin{cases}
n-1, & \text{if }n \text{ is even}\\
2n, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$

I am asked to find $fg$ and $gf$, the notation that my textbook uses for the compositions $f(g(n))$ and $g(f(n))$ respectively. My professor gave me the hint that I will have three cases for at least one of the compositions.

--update--

For the compositions I got these answers:

$fg(n) =
\begin{cases}
n, & \text{if }n \text{ is even}\\
n, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases} = n$

$gf(n) =
\begin{cases}
n, & \text{if } n\neq4t, t \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\frac{n}{2}-1, & \text{if }n = 4t, t \in \mathbb{Z} \\
n, & \text{if }n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$

Do these appear to be the correct answers?

Comment: Almost. Notice that if $n$ is odd, then $f(n)$ is even, and then $g(f(n)) = n$. Also, if $n$ is an even multiple of $4$, then $f(n)$ is even and thus $g(f(n)) = \frac{n}{2} - 1$. Then the last case if that $n$ is even but not a multiple of $4$, then $f(n)$ is odd and then $g(f(n)) = n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it for $f(g(n))$. The other composition is left to you ;)

If $n$ is even, $g(n) = n-1$ is odd. Then,

$$f(g(n))=f(n-1)=n-1+1=n\,.$$

On the other hand if $n$ is odd, $g(n)=2n$ is even. Then,

$$f(g(n))=f(2n)=\frac{2n}{2}=n\,.$$

It follows that $f(g)$ is the identity.

---

You should apply an analogous reasoning to compute $g(f(n))$, paying now some extra care when $n$ is even (hint: there is a difference on whether $4$ divides it or not). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe so! I got the identity for $fg$ so that makes me a little more confident. Would you mind to check the answer for $gf$ that I just added to my original question? Thank you!

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $f(n)=n+1$ is even. Then, $g(f(n)) = n+1-1 =n$. I think you write the $n=4t$ and $n$ even but $n\neq 4t$ the other way round.

Comment: You're right; I went back over my work and fixed my errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Further hint when you compute $g(f(n))$:

The three cases are:

- When $n$ is odd, then $f(n)$ is even. Use the appropriate rule for $g$ on $f(n)$.
- When $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then $f(n)$ is also even, use the appropriate rule for $g$ on $f(n)$.
- When $n$ is even but not a multiple of $4$, then $f(n)$ is odd, use the appropriate rule for $g$ on $f(n)$.